# problem when using pyfmi: " terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::filesystem::__cxx11::filesystem_error "

Tags: python, pyfmi, energyplus

I am using pyfmi on Ubuntu system for a co-simulation of Energyplus FMU file and Python and met this error when trying to create the co-simulation.

```
Reading input and weather file for preprocessor program.
The IDF version of the input file ///tmp/JModelica.org/jm_tmpjzpnl48l//resources//in.idf starts with 22
Successfully finish reading weather file.
This is the Begin Month: 1
Time (0) set is smaller than minimun allowed (1 day). Day will be set to 1.
This is the Day of the Begin Month: 1
This is the End Month: 1
This is the Day of the End Month: 31
This is the New Day of Week: FRIDAY
[INFO][Slave] [ok][FMU status:OK] This version uses the **energyplus** command line interface to  call the EnergyPlus executable. **RunEPlus.bat** and **runenergyplus** , which were used in earlier versions, were deprecated as of August 2015.
Running EPMacro...
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::filesystem::__cxx11::filesystem_error'
  what():  filesystem error: cannot create symlink: File exists [in.epmidf] [in.idf]
```

It says the files exist, but I am sure there was no such files before running it. I used sudo, so it shouldn't be a permissions issue.
I have tried it on Ubuntu 20.04 and Ubuntu 22.04 and always the same error. I tried the same code but another FMU file, it works well.

Thank you if you have any suggestions.